# loading JSON file in angular controller, with grouped data

Tags: angularjs, json

I cannot load my JSON file in angular.

[Pulnker :](http://plnkr.co/edit/bMNtEklZQxnTCXXBmBAR?p=preview)

```
 $http.get("aDATA.JSON").success(function(data) {
 $scope.items= data;
 });
```

but on groupings it doesnt show anything

```
 $scope.headCells = _.keys(_.groupBy($scope.items, function(item){ return item.year}));
      $scope.rows = _.groupBy($scope.items, function(item){ return item.name});

  $scope.sortByYearProp = function(values){
    return _.sortBy(values, function(value){
      return value.year;
    });
  }
```

Comment: the link is actually in the "this is my plnkr"

Comment: You should make it simpler for people to help you, not harder. You have very simple problem that is obvious from just looking at it, but you would get much better answers if you posted code in the question, present it nicely. I think the only reason why after 12 minutes you don't have single answer for such a simple problem is because you didn't format your question properly. First few minutes are very important.

Comment: thanks i hope by this update, it looks simpler now :)

Comment: Your problem is that you are trying to manipulate data before it's loaded (remember that AJAX is async). Correct code could be: http://plnkr.co/edit/IDYG7JFcm8SKKEZXZRoU?p=preview

Comment: new to angular.. thanks mate :) big help! from a big heart!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the `lodash` grouping in the success function like this, otherwise there is no data to loop through because it's fired before the JSON data is present in the controller.

```
$http.get("aDATA.JSON").success(function(data) {
  $scope.items= data;
  $scope.headCells = _.keys(_.groupBy($scope.items, function(item){ return item.year}));
  $scope.rows = _.groupBy($scope.items, function(item){ return item.name});
});
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/zjf0fIJUzT6FWfRYVsO6?p=preview

Comment: Yeah I noticed the question was answered in the comments while I was putting up a plunker for example :D